How to create a minor release with only some commits
I'm using the standard git flow.
In some cases I need to create a minor release choosing a subset of all the commits done in develop branch.
Let's say I closed my last release and merged it back to develop in commit X. Now I created new commits, x1,x2,x3,x4,x5
develop -------x----x1----x2----x3----x4----x5
release/3.4---/--\
master-----------y(tag 3.4)--------

I want to create release/3.5 adding only x1 and x4. What is the best solution?
My ideas (none of them seems totally right though):

start from develop, revert the commits x2,x3,x5
start from tag 3.4 in master branch and cherry-pick x1 and x4. at the end I don't merge back to develop (but I merge to master)


Is the intention to still release all of develop at some point, but just not yet? If yes, then this would indeed be a hotfix instead of a mini "release", as described in Finbar's answer.

Continuing my previous thought, if you wish to release develop as is in the next "release", then #2 is the answer, and it's called a hotfix. If you do not intend to release those 3 commits in the next release (or ever), then #1 is the answer, and you can create a normal release from develop.

Side note, sometimes when you have a release branch in progress, if someone accidentally merges a bug fix into develop instead of release, then you fix it by cherry-picking that bug fix over into release. Since you don't currently have a pending release, whether you cherry-pick 2 commits from develop into a branch named release, or instead to a branch named hotfix, doesn't actually make a difference...

Option 2 looks right to me - you're effectively doing a hotfix in gitflow https://nvie.com/files/Git-branching-model.pdf

but in the model hotfixes are then merged back to develop, aren't they?

I'm not sure what the issue is with merging back into develop.  Your commits x1 and x4 are already in develop.

often when I merge back i get conflicts, or old commits override new commits, in fact reverting the new deployments

While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

@tuttfo19 - can you please expand on how you are getting conflicts merging from the hotfix back into the develop branch?  These commits x1 and x4 are already in develop so shouldn't cause a merge conflict.Can you also please expand on how old commits override new commits?  If you don't want the commits x2, x3 and x5 AT ALL then you would be better removing them as in option 1.  If there's something else going on, like you're trying to support multiple releases at the same time, please let us know so we can help better.

@nol4635 thank you for your feedback.  I can provide a more detailed answer when I have a clearer idea of the problem, as it sounds like there's something else going on here and when we have the answers to mine and TTT's questions that will be clearer.  Just for context, the questioner had already provided that link and presented 2 options that I thought they were familiar with and didn't need further detail on how to implement, just guidance on which one to choose.
